# Get normalized representation of SET datatype

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select

In MySQL you can SELECT SET values from a table using this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_set` (
  `int` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `set_2` set('a','b','c') DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

SELECT * FROM test_set WHERE set_2 & 1;
```

or equivalent using `=` operator.

For a given table:

```
int | set_2
-----------
12  | a,b
-----------
34  | c,b
```

I'd like to make a query that would return:

```
int | set_2
-----------
12  | a
-----------
12  | b
-----------
34  | c
-----------
34  | b
```

How would such query look in mysql/mariadb? According to the book I am reading, it should be something in the lines of:

```
SELECT T.int, S as set_value
FROM test_set T, T.set_2 as S
```

Similarly, `set_gen()` function can be applied to reverse normalized representation to the one containing sets:

```
SELECT T.int, set_gen(T.set_2) 
FROM test_set T
GROUP BY T.int
```

What is the syntax for denormalization in mysql/mariadb?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `int`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`set_2`, ',', `mask`), ',', -1) `set`
FROM `test_set`, 
      -- generate masks based on SET values list count
     (SELECT 1 `mask` UNION 
      SELECT 2 UNION 
      SELECT 3) `mask`
WHERE `set_2` & 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0cdd72f9e35e5a032ced8292d214e44a)

If server version allows build `mask` in recursive CTE (dynamic count may be used)